# cardinality of polynomial

Tags: cardinals, equivalence-relations

What is the cardinality of the following sets?
(Choose from finite, countably infinite, or uncountably infinite.)

The set of polynomials of the form $ax+b$ with $a \in\Bbb N$ and

1. $b \in\{0,1\}$
2. $b \in\Bbb N$
3. $b \in\Bbb Q$
4. $b \in\Bbb R$
5. $b \in\Bbb C$

Comment: 1. A lot   2. Even more  3. I have my own homework to do.

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: You should tell us what you know and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Any set X with cardinality less than that of the natural numbers, or | X | < | N |, is said to be a finite set.

Any set X that has the same cardinality as the set of the natural numbers, or | X | = | N | = \aleph_0, is said to be a countably infinite set.

Any set X with cardinality greater than that of the natural numbers, or | X | > | N |, for example | R | = \mathfrak c  > | N |, is said to be uncountable.

(a) a set from natural number to {0,1} is countably infinite. Am i correct? What is the approach to this question that i should look for?

Comment: Sorry. I thought I deleted my comment. I was implying that you ought to show some effort, as @Lubin said, though my way of saying it was far less charitable, and perhaps inappropriate.

Comment: I have mentioned that.

Comment: There are a few theorems you should be aware of. For instance, that if $A$ and $B$ are countable, then so is $A\times B$.

Comment: There is a bijection between polynomials $ax+b$ with $a\in\Bbb N$ and $b\in S$ and the Cartesian product $\Bbb N\times S$. Thus, you need to know something about the cardinalities of the products $\Bbb N\times S$ for $S=\{0,1\},\Bbb N,\Bbb Q,\Bbb R,\Bbb $C$. Lubin’s hint is very useful here.

Answer (score 0):

First, is the domain of $x$ all real numbers or is it relative to each of the sets listed out in (1) - (5)?

After thinking about this, ask yourself the following questions:

(1) Given that $a \in \mathbb{N}$, and that $b \in \{0,1\}$, does adding a set of finite elements to that of an infinite set change the total cardinality of the union of both sets?

(2) Does the union of two sets with cardinality = $\mathbb{N}$ equal to $\mathbb{N}$ or something else?

(3) Are the rationals equinumerous to the naturals?

(4) Are the Reals equinumerous to the naturals? (Hint: read about Cantor Diagonalization)

(5) How are the Complex Numbers defined? Does their definition, coupled with your answer to question (4), dictate the cardinality?